# How to update subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to update the subdocument FinanceSchema.Here is my model

```
            const FinanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
              moneyToBePaid: {
                type: Number,
              },
            
              moneyPaid: {
                type: Number,
              },
            
              moneyToBeReceived: {
                type: Number,
              },
            
              moneyReceived: {
                type: Number,
              },
            });
            
            const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
              financialInformation: [FinanceSchema],
            });
            module.exports=mongoose.model('user',UserSchema)
```

This is the route

I am able to post finance info

```
        router.post("/users/:id/profile", async (req, res) => {
          const _id = req.params.id;
          const {
            moneyToBePaid,
            moneyPaid,
            moneyToBeReceived,
            moneyReceived,
          } = req.body;
          const finance = {
            moneyToBePaid,
            moneyPaid,
            moneyToBeReceived,
            moneyReceived,
          };
          try {
            const user = await User.findById(_id);
            user.financialInformation.unshift(finance);
            await user.save();
        }
```

I am not able to update the `financeInformation(FinanceSchema)`.I am confused how to define the route and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [markModified()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified) as mongoose might not pick up the change automatically:

```
const user = await User.findById(_id);
user.financialInformation.unshift(finance);
user.markModified('financialInformation');
await user.save();
```

---

EDIT:

If you want to modify the `financialInformation` at a certain index, you can simply do the following:

```
const user = await User.findById(_id);
user.financialInformation[0].moneyReceived = 1000000;
await user.save();
```

Comment: I am able to push financialInfo in user schema.My only issue is I am not able to update a particular financialInfo which is an array.

Comment: You mean you want to update the `financialInformation` at a certain index? Or all array elements?

Comment: See my edit. There I modify the value for `moneyReceived` on index `0`.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please make sure to accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Actaully both.eg. A user has 3 financialInformation.I should be able to update all 3 of them or a single one of them.

Comment: Well, if you need to update all, just loop over the array?